# Unexpected null value,neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I don't know why I can't get the value of the `movie` fields. I debugged it and I found the `movie` is null. I post a picture and you will see it[image]. Please give me some advice. I am sure I had created the relationship successfully, may somewhere wrong with recommendation. Class or cypher?

```
public interface MovieRepository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {


@Query("match (user:User {login: {0}})-[r:RATED]->(movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(other)-[r3:RATED]->(otherMovie) "
        + " where r.stars >= 3 and r2.stars >= r.stars and r3.stars >= r.stars "
        + " with otherMovie, avg(r3.stars) as rating, count(*) as cnt" 
        + " order by rating desc, cnt desc"
        + " return otherMovie as movie, rating limit 10")
List<MovieRecommendation> getRecommendations(String login);

}
```

recommend.class

```
@QueryResult
public class MovieRecommendation {


Movie movie;
int rating;
public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}
public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}
public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
   }
}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String profile(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    if (user != null) {
        List<MovieRecommendation> mr = movieRepository.getRecommendations(user.getLogin());
    MovieRecommendation movie = new MovieRecommendation();
    Movie m = new Movie();
    m.setTitle("AA");
    movie.setMovie(m);
    mr.add(movie);
    model.addAttribute("recommendations", mr);
    }
    return "user/index";
}
```

run cypher use neo4j-community

```
match (user:ollie)-[r:RATED]->(movie)<-[r2:RATED]-(other)-[r3:RATED]->(otherMovie) 
where r.stars >= 1 and r2.stars >= r.stars and r3.stars >= r.stars 
with otherMovie, avg(r3.stars) as rating, count(*) as cnt
order by rating desc, cnt desc
return otherMovie limit 10
```

Comment: hi,Opal..do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to figure out how  `MovieRecommendation` instance is created. Whoever creates it does not call `setMovie` or calls it with `null`. Put a breakpoint on `setMovie` method and on `Movie` constructor. Could it be that you have a recommendation record in your DB that links to non-existing movie? Do you use foreign key constraint?

Comment: Can you share your actual query results when you run the query manually?

Comment: Michael,i run the cypher on neo4j-community it return 0 row,but in project it just can't get the movie information,why?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query returns null.

So the first element [0] have a movie which is null...

The movie 'AA' should be in [1] in your array because you make the query and after it you append the recommendation

Comment: but i can get the amount of movie,AA is my add after excute the cypher,may i can't resolve the elements which i got?